# Java centos and system time

Tags: java, centos, tomcat

Добрый день!

Суть: на сервере крутится tomcat, в нем - приложение, и время, которое получается в приложение через `new Date()` и даже

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Расходится с тем, что я получаю вызывая `date` или `date -u` или  `hwclock --show`

На сайте время отображается вообще другое, независящее от установленного текущего, выражается в том, что при изменение времени системного и перезапуске tomcat - время на сайте идет так же, как и без изменения времени.
Так же уточню, что время отличается не только часовым поясом, но и минутами (сейчас 28 по серверу и 46 на сайте).

Томкат и сам сервер перезагружал, в чем может быть проблема ? Спасибо.

Comment: А разное насколько? Может проблема с часовыми поясами.

Comment: Настолько, что время на сайте идет, но не изменяется при изменение системного времени.

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста поподробнее сценарий, прям в вопросе.

Comment: google://tomcat+timezone. пара первых результатов: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28777322/4827341 http://stackoverflow.com/q/28777322/4827341

Comment: Может, вы смотрите на неправильном сервере? Т.е. вы думаете, что томкат запущен на сервере `А`, а на самом деле он запущен на сервере `Б` (а на сервере `А` запущен какой-то другой, не относящийся к делу томкат).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы дали одну ссылку два раза :)

Comment: Изменив часовой пояс получилось получить нужный часовой пояс по UTC. но минуты различаются

Answer (score 1):

Все нормализовалось после добавления

```
TOMCAT_TIMEZONE="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Moscow"
JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Moscow -Xms1g -Xmx2g"
export PATH JAVA_HOME JAVA_OPTS JRE_HOME
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $TOMCAT_TIMEZONE"
```